# access drive owned by windows in linux

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows, boot-partition

I dual boot windows and linux, one one drive I have linux and in the other I split it in to two partitions one for windows and other for games, I intend to use windows just to play games on since linux dose not support games I like to play, I want to have the partition for games be shared between the two systems, I can mount the partition no problem but when I what to delete or make files I don't have permission to do so

Comment: You've not provided any Ubuntu product/release details; but if you mount a *unclean* file-system (*where all data hasn't been written to disk, which occurs with a hibernated system, which includes windows fastboot*), you have only RO access.  Are you sure it's a permissions issue? and not just a mounting issue (*due to unclean status detected, where RO prevents dataloss*)

Comment: Ubuntu LTS, I dont know what issue is I can mount and unmount partition but I cant delete or make new files

Comment: What version of ubuntu LTS? paste a screenshot of the output given by `lsb_release -a`